# How to control how vim measures paragraphs

Tags: vim

When editing latex code in vim, I often type `gwap` to rejustify the current paragraph. Unfortunately when the paragraph contains equations or other similar latex control code the formatting is all mixed up.

For example if I try to rejustify the nicely justified paragraph

```
Our network model follows that of Nakajima et
al.~\\cite{nakajima_robustness_2010} which is in turn based on the model of Li
et al.~\\cite{li_yeast_2004}. We define the dynamics of a network through the
following recurrence relation
\\[
X_i^{t+1} = \\left\\{ \\begin{array}{cl}
  1 & \\textrm{if $\\sum_j J_{ij} X_j^t > 0$} \\\\
  0 & \\textrm{if $\\sum_j J_{ij} X_j^t < 0$} \\\\
  \\theta_i & \\textrm{if $\\sum_j J_{ij} X_j^t = 0$}
\\end{array} \\right.
\\]
$X_i^t \\in \\{0, 1\\}$ is the expression state of gene $i$ at time point $t$.
$J_{ij}$ represents the regulatory effect of gene $j$ on gene $i$. $J_{ij} >
0$, $J_{ij} < 0$ and $J_{ij} = 0$  imply activation, repression and the absence
of regulation respectively. $\\theta_i$ is the constitutive expression state of
gene $i$.
```

then I end up with this mess:

```
Our network model follows that of Nakajima et
al.~\\cite{nakajima_robustness_2010} which is in turn based on the model of Li
et al.~\\cite{li_yeast_2004}. We define the dynamics of a network through the
following recurrence relation \\[ X_i^{t+1} = \\left\\{ \\begin{array}{cl} 1 &
                              \\textrm{if $\\sum_j J_{ij} X_j^t > 0$} \\\\ 0 &
                       \\textrm{if $\\sum_j J_{ij} X_j^t < 0$} \\\\ \\theta_i &
                       \\textrm{if $\\sum_j J_{ij} X_j^t = 0$} \\end{array}
                   \\right.  \\] $X_i^t \\in \\{0, 1\\}$ is the expression state of
                   gene $i$ at time point $t$.  $J_{ij}$ represents the
                   regulatory effect of gene $j$ on gene $i$. $J_{ij} > 0$,
                   $J_{ij} < 0$ and $J_{ij} = 0$  imply activation, repression
                   and the absence of regulation respectively. $\\theta_i$ is
                   the constitutive expression state of gene $i$.
```

How can I tell vim that paragraphs shouldn't span code like `\[ \] \begin{} \end{}`?

Thanks,
John.

Comment: I feel this should be here, as comment, so I deleted my answer. `:h paragraph` for para info. `:h paragraphs` is the option to set, how to separate paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks. How do set the paragraphs option just for latex mode?

Answer (score 0):

The notion of *paragraphs* comes from the old *vi*-heritage of *nroff macros* (whatever that is :-); it cannot be changed substantially. Recently, a patch was floated on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php) to [support custom definitions via regular expressions](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/eabeaa5fc5ba23f6).

So far, you have to work around the problem by using a visual selection instead: `Vjjjgw`. Or, you could write your own text objects for *Tex* paragraphs.

Comment: I'm an old hand at vim but to my shame I've never really used anything more than a few basic editing and motion commands. Can I define new motion commands that understand paragraph boundaries? Then can I use them as part of my gwap command?

Comment: Custom motions are `:nmap` commands that reposition the cursor, and text objects are `:omap`s. You can use my [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130) to define those based on regular expressions.